# Download data in Dockerfile and use it in volume

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I want to clone a git repo, install a fresh neos.io or something like that in the `Dockerfile` via `RUN`. Later on I want to mount the directory including the files into my local filesystem.
According to [this github issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/4361) its not possible since 
 mounting the volume will remove the data.

How to archive the wanted behaviour? Using `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT` will clone the git repo f.e. on every start. Thats not necessary.

Dockerfile

```
FROM debian:stable

RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y git

WORKDIR /home/app

RUN git clone https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2

CMD ["sleep", "infinity"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "2"
services:
  app:
    build: .
    # Uncomment this will remove data on docker-compose up
    # volumes:
    #   - ./app:/home/app
```

Comment: What's your higher-level use case?  Why wouldn't you just run `git clone` on the host?  What is this container supposed to actually do when you start it?

Comment: For instance I want to use this image multiple times. And every time I use it I dont want to `git clone` on the host again.

Answer (score 0):

You can clone the repo to an arbitrary directory, say `/home/app-clone` for example, then in your `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD`, you copy the files from this directory to your volume directory, so something like:

```
.
.
RUN git clone https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2 /home/app-clone
CMD cp -r /home/app-clone /home/app && sleep infinity
```

Answer (score 0):

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM debian:stable

RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y git

WORKDIR /home/app

RUN git clone https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2.git

CMD ["cp", "-r", "libgit2", "/tmp"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "2"
services:
  app:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ./app:/tmp
```